# Python netcat not returning command shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

The code below is meant to copy the features of netcat for instances where netcat is removed from a server but python is not. However, no matter what I try I can't seem to figure out the following problem:
I run the following

`./Netcat.py -l -p 9999 -c`

followed by

`./Netcat.py -t localhost -p 9999`

in a separate terminal. I can confirm that, when acting as a server the script does, indeed, receive a connection from the second instance of the script and that it receives data when it is set (upon pressing CTRL+D). However, I then get a hung terminal which does not receive a command prompt back, nor does it have the ability to send more data. I am hoping someone can point out the error at this point.

What should happen is as follows:

1. spin up server insatance
2. run script as a client
3. type some data and close STDIN with CTRL+D at which point the client sends the data to the server
4. The server should then receive the data and send back a command prompt to the client

The problem is at step 4 and I'm pulling my hair out at this point.

### Edit

Having run strace I determined that the client program gets hung up waiting to receive data which I have noted the corresponding line in the code. I do not see why this would be the case.

```
import sys                #  used for accessing command line args
import socket             #  creation of socket objects to listen & send/receive data
import getopt             #  helps scripts to parse the command line arguments in sys.argv
import concurrent.futures #  for running commands in a subshell
import subprocess         #  The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes.


##  Globals  ##
listen             = False
command            = False
target             = ""
port               = 0
## END GLOBALS ##


def client_sender(buffer):
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        client.connect((target, port))

        if len(buffer):
            # bytes([source[, encoding[, errors]]])
            client.send(bytes(buffer, 'utf-8'))

        # continue sending and receiving data until user kills script
        while True:

            recv_len = 1
            response = ''

            while recv_len:

                data      = client.recv(4096) #<-- PROBLEM
                recv_len  = len(data)
                response += data.decode('utf-8')

                if recv_len < 4096:
                    break

                print(response)

            buffer = input('#: ')
            buffer += '\n'

            client.send(buffer)

    except socket.error as e:

        print('[*] Exception! Exiting')
        print(e)

        client.close()


def server_loop():
    global target
    global port
    # if no target is defined, listen on all interfaces
    if not len(target):
        target = '0.0.0.0'

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((target, port))

    server.listen(5)
    print(f'listening on {target}:{port}')

    while True:
        client_socket, addr = server.accept()

        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
            executor.submit(client_handler, client_socket)


def run_command(command):

    command = command.rstrip()

    # run command & retrieve output
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    except:
        return 'Failed to execute command.\r\n'


def client_handler(client_socket):
    global command

    # check if shell requested
    if command:

        while True:
            client_socket.send('<BHP:#> ')

            # receive until linefeed
            cmd_buffer = ''
            while '\n' not in cmd_buffer:
                cmd_buffer += client_socket.recv(1024)

            response = run_command(bufffer)
            client_socket.send(response)


def main():
    global listen
    global port
    global command
    global target

    # make sure the user provided options & arguments
    if not len(sys.argv[1:]):
        usage()

    # parse commandline options
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],"lt:p:c", #: succeeds options which expect an argument
                                    ['listen', 'target', 'port', 'command'])
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        print(str(err))
        usage()

    # handle commandline options
    for option, argument in opts:

        elif option in ('-l', '--listen'):
            listen = True
        elif option in ('-e', '--execute'):
            execute = argument
        elif option in ('-c', '--commandshell'):
            command = True
        elif option in ('-t', '--target'):
            target = argument
        elif option in ('-p', '--port'):
            port = int(argument)

    # not listening; sending data from stdin
    if not listen and len(target) and port > 0:
        buffer = sys.stdin.read()

        client_sender(buffer)

    if listen:
        server_loop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I know the code is a bit extensive but this is a minimal working example.

Comment: "Minimal" means "nothing further could be taken out while still reproducing the problem". That's surely untrue here; there's still a bunch of command-line parsing, optional functionality (for file upload, f/e) etc.

Comment: That said -- debugging this, my first point of call would be sysdig, bpftrace, strace (with the `-f` argument to be tracing all processes in the tree), or other syscall-tracing tooling of that ilk. That way you could actually look at which specific OS-level events are and are not happening. (Is the Python interpreter actually receiving the incoming data? Is it writing out the FIFO to the shell? Is the shell writing to the other FIFO with a result? Is Python reading that result? etc). Once you know that, you'll be able to write a narrower question.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I managed to narrow things down a bit and strip out more unnecessary code.